# If в python, проблема с кодом

Tags: python, if

Мне нужно чтобы if выполнялся не только при одном значении допустим Погода, но и при его вариациях там погода, покажи погоду и т.д подскажите пожалуйста как

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys
from name import Ui_Dialog
import geocoder
import pyowm
import datetime
cmd=['Погода','погода']
now = datetime.datetime.now()
he = "Джеймс: "
you = "Вы: "
app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

Dialog=QtWidgets.QDialog()

ui=Ui_Dialog()

ui.setupUi(Dialog)

Dialog.show()
def send():
   tbr = ui.lineEdit.text()

   if tbr == 'Погода':
       g = geocoder.ip('me')
       owm = pyowm.OWM('api', language='ru')
       observation = owm.weather_at_coords(*g.latlng)
       w = observation.get_weather()
       temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
       ui.label.setText(you + tbr)
       ui.label_2.setText(he + " У вас сейчас " + str(temp) + "°С. " + "Облачность: " + 
                          w.get_detailed_status())

   if tbr == 'Текущее время':
       ui.label.setText(you + tbr)
       ui.label_2.setText(he + "Сейчас " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))
       ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(send)
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте поиск переменной в кортедже или чём-нибудь схожем.

Пример:

```
if tbr in ("Погода", "погода", "покажи погоду", "Weather", "weather"):
    ...
```

Comment: Лучше во множестве и проверять в одном регистре.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы проверял ещё универсальнее чем в другом ответе:

```
tbr = tbr.lower()
if 'погод' in tbr or 'weather' in tbr:
    # сработает на любую фразу где есть 'погода' в любом падеже и регистре, либо 'weather'
elif 'врем' in tbr or 'time' in tbr:
    # сработает на любую фразу где есть 'время' в любом падеже и регистре, либо 'time'
else:
    # неизвестная команда
```

Comment: Спасибо CrazyElf, можете ещё подсказать как при условии что команда не соответствует существующим вывести сообщение по типу - Неизвестная команда, повторите попытку?